# X is sequentially compact $\implies $ then Lebesgue lemma hold for X where X is metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

> X is sequentially compact $\implies $ then Lebesgue lemma hold for X where X is metric space
>
> Lebesgue lemma:X is said to satisfy Lebesgue number lemma it  for every open cover of X there in $\delta >0$ wherever there is set with diameter $\delta $ then it contains completely in some element of the open cover

I had read proof from Munkres as follows [image]

I had the following doubts:

1) $x_n $ is constructed in such a way that it implies sequence itself convergent.

I know that by sequentially compactness we get convergent subsequence.

But construction says that $x_n\in B(t,1/n)$ due to this I think there is no choice for sequence rather than to converge. AS we know that it has a convergent subsequence that means sequence converges to the same point

Is my interpretation is correct?

2)I read theorem several times but I do not think I get an idea how to arrive at contradiction.

Please help me to learn this theorem .

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: @ThomasShelby Dear Sir I got that Point . But why does then sequncetial compact ness required as we are already constructing sequnce that will definitely converging. ...Is that required to ensure completeness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-empty $C_n$ with $\operatorname{diam}(C_n) < \frac1n$ are given separately from each other: the contradiction-assumption only gives they such sets exist (such that $C_n$ is also not a subset of *any* $A \in \mathcal{A}$) not that we can choose them to be nested, or of the form $B(a,r)$ for some $a,r$ etc. We know nothing at all about them, except their diameter and non-subset properties. That's why we pick $x_n \in C_n$ and use a convergent subsequence of them to get any "grip" on them at all. So we have a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ that converges to some $a \in X$. As $\mathcal{A}$ is a cover, we have some $A_0 \in \mathcal{A}$ that contains this $a$. As $A_0$ is open, there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(a,\varepsilon) \subseteq A_0$. So far so good.

Now $B(a, \varepsilon)$ has diameter $\le 2\varepsilon$, and it contains infinitely many $x_{n_k}$ (as they converge to $a$) which come from sets of smaller and smaller diameter, so eventually the $C_{n_k}$ they came from are also going to fit inside $B(a,\varepsilon)$: just pick $i$ so large that $\frac{1}{n_i} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and also such that $d(x_{n_i},a) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, then let $p \in C_{n_i}$. As $p$ and $x_{n_i}$ both comes from $C_{ni}$: $d(p, x_{n_i}) \le \operatorname{diam}(C_{n_i}) < \frac{1}{n_i} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and so $$d(p,a) \le d(p, x_{n_i}) + d(x_{n_i},a) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$

and as $p \in C_{n_i}$ was arbitrary, $$C_{n_i} \subseteq B(a, \varepsilon) \subseteq A_0$$

which is in immediate contradiction with the fact that no $C_m$ was a subset of *any* subset of $\mathcal{A}$ by assumption!

The triangle inequality argument was not written down by Munkres (as such arguments are so common that the reader is supposed to fill them in him/herself), but the intuition should be clear: the convergent subsequence forces the small corresponding $C_n$ sets to cluster near $a$ too, and so inside the open $A_0$ that $a$ is in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choosing $x_n$ from $C_n$ which satisfies that $\mbox{diam}C_n<1/n$ and is not contained in any element of $\mathcal{A}$( by hypothesis, $C_n$ exists ), no condition ganrantees that $x_n$ converges, but by sequentially compactness of $X$, there exists a convergence subsequence $y_n$ of $x_n$.
2. $C_{n_i}\subset A$ contradicts with the hypothesis that any $C_n$ is not contained in any element of $\mathcal{A}$ .